# Make a separate conditional rendering inside for loop react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [isAgent, setAgent] = useState(true);

  {isSupervisor.map((value, index) => {

  return <div className="text-gray-700 rounded-lg" key={index}>
    {isAgent ? <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className=" flex-none text-center">
            <div>Halo</div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-grow text-gray-700 px-2 py-1 my-auto">
           <button onClick={() => setAgent(true)} className="bg-custom-14 ">Edit</button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> : <div>
     <div className="flex flex-col my-2 mx-8">
        <div className=" flex-none text-center">
            <div>Halo</div>
        </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end">
              <button onClick={() => setAgent(false)} className="bg-custom-14">Discard</button>
          </div>
   </div> </div>
```

problem:
when i click a condition button, all button follow the condition, is there any solution to make a separate condition in every button ? thanks

Comment: This is a little tricky for me to understand because there is so much unnecessary code and your question is unclear. :) But perhaps your problem could be solved by extracting the buttons into their own components with their own local state?

Comment: can you please describe more and remove unnecessary code .

Comment: Please explain your code and elaborate your question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer assuming that in this list of sections with buttons you only need to change one section on clicking 'edit'.
Since `isAgent` and `setAgent` affect all sections at once, your state should have a map of states for each sections, `isAgent` should be a function to retrieve balue from this state by a section key, and `setAgent` should accept the section key.
So, your react state may look ike this:

```
class State {
  editingAgents = {};
  isAgent = (index) => editingAgents[index];
  setAgents = (index, isAgent) => editingAgents[index] = isAgent;
}
```

and modified component code may be like this (notice how `isAgent` and `setAgent` are used now)

```
const [isAgent, setAgent] = useState(true);

  {isSupervisor.map((value, index) => {

  return <div className="text-gray-700 hover:bg-custom-8 rounded-lg" key={index}>
    {isAgent(index) ? <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className=" flex-none text-center mx-2 my-1">
            <img src={Ane} className=" w-54px lg:w-50px object-contain"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-grow text-gray-700 px-2 py-1 my-auto">
           <button onClick={() => setAgent(index, true)} className="bg-custom-14 ">Edit</button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> : <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updateAgent)}>
     <div className="flex flex-col my-2 mx-8">
        <div className="m-2 lg:mt-4 hidden">
            <div className="inline-block w-3/12 text-base lg:text-sm font-semibold">Id</div>
        </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end">
              <button onClick={() => setAgent(index, false)} className="bg-custom-14">Discard</button>
          </div>
   </div> </form>
```